# Python Ariadne GraphQL "cannot import name 'GraphQLNamedType'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, ariadne-graphql

I am using Ariadne with Flask.

When I try `from ariadne import QueryType, graphql_sync, make_executable_schema` as indicated in the [Ariadne's doc for Flask](https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/flask-integration.html) I get the following error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GraphQLNamedType'
```

I am using :

- Python 3.5.1
- ariadne-0.11.0
- graphql-core-2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue came from `graphql-core` version which need to be >=3.

I was unabled to install the version >=3 so I upgraded Python to 3.8. When installing Ariadne, I get the same version 0.11.0 but now the graphql-core version 3.0.5 and no more the error.

Comment: Do you really not have any errors with graphql-core 3.1.1?, I installed graphql-core 3.1.2 and then I got a new error, Now I have 3.0.5 and no errors.

Comment: Sorry I have the 3.0.5 version I just checked, I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

At the moment Ariadne is not compatible with many of the graphql-core, so the version should be between 3.0 and 3.1 for Ariadne to work.

```
pip install "graphql-core<3.1"
```

Her is some sources:

https://github.com/mirumee/ariadne/issues/345

https://graphql-core-3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#getting-started